# Send JSON Object data in window.open in LWC Salesforce

Tags: javascript, json, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to send the below JSON object in Window.Open, but when i trying to retrieve it, i am getting

> "[object Object]"

```
@track InputValues = {
    strName: "test",
    strAddress: "test",
    strCountry: "test",
    strCode: "1",
    strNumber: "1"
  };



 window.open("/c/testApp.app?recordId="+this.recordId +"&getallinputs="+this.InputValues,'_blank');
```

Aura testApp

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" access="GLOBAL" implements="force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" default="123"/>
     <aura:attribute name="getallinputs" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <c:test recordId="{!v.recordId}" jsonDetails="{!v.getallinputs}"/>
</aura:application>
```

At Receiving LWC end -

```
renderedCallback() {
    this.dataJson = JSON.stringify(this.InputValues);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply JSON.stringify() around the obj to be able to view it.

```
let inputVal = JSON.stringify(this.InputValues);    
window.open("/c/testApp.app?recordId="+this.recordId +"&getallinputs="+inputVal ,'_blank');
```